# Swift iOS: EXC_BAD_ACCESS during attempt to fetch value by key from AnyObject

Tags: ios, swift

I have default `Dictionary`:

```
 var activeLanguage:Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = [
                                                    "name":"English",
                                                    "tag":"en",
                                                    "change_by_user":false,
                                                    "css_path":""
                                                    ]
```

From application user I get new configuration and my goal is to validate fields and store new value to `activeLanguage` (a.e replace with new ones). If some key doesn't exist I put default value. Nothing complicated.

Here is my implementation:

```
 func build(obj:AnyObject){

        if let tempDict:Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = obj["activeLanguage"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{

            self.activeLanguage["name"] = tempDict["name"] as? String ?? activeLanguage["name"] // <-- CRASH here
            self.activeLanguage["tag"] = tempDict["tag"] as? String ?? activeLanguage["tag"]
            self.activeLanguage["change_by_user"] = tempDict["change_by_user"] as? Bool ?? false
            self.activeLanguage["css_path"] = tempDict["css_path"] as? String ?? activeLanguage["css_path"]

        }
}
```

I tested on several clients but on one application crashes on line:

```
self.activeLanguage["name"] = tempDict["name"] as? String ?? activeLanguage["name"]
```

*Full stack trace:*

EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001ae36bec8

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x00000001004a17d0 swift_unknownRelease + 24
1  MyApp                       0x00000001000a4654 specialization <Swift.String with Swift.String : Swift.Hashable, Swift.AnyObject> of Swift._VariantDictionaryStorage.ensureUniqueNativeStorage <A : Swift.Hashable, B>(inout Swift._VariantDictionaryStorage<A, B>)(Swift.Int) -> (reallocated : Swift.Bool, capacityChanged : Swift.Bool) (MyAppPlugin.swift)
2  MyApp                       0x00000001000a2800 specialization <Swift.String with Swift.String : Swift.Hashable, Swift.AnyObject> of Swift._VariantDictionaryStorage.nativeUpdateValue <A : Swift.Hashable, B>(inout Swift._VariantDictionaryStorage<A, B>)(B, forKey : A) -> Swift.Optional<B> (MyAppPlugin.swift)
3  MyApp                       0x00000001000a1fa4 specialization <Swift.String with Swift.String : Swift.Hashable, Swift.AnyObject> of Swift.Dictionary.subscript.setter (A) -> Swift.Optional<B> (MyAppPlugin.swift)
4  MyApp                       0x00000001001a93e8 MyApp.WmConfigModel.build (MyApp.WmConfigModel)(Swift.AnyObject) -> () (WmConfigModel.swift:84)
5  MyApp                       0x00000001001ced54 MyApp.WmSettingsMgr.setSettings (MyApp.WmSettingsMgr.Type)(Swift.AnyObject) -> () (WmSettingsMgr.swift:29)
6  MyApp                       0x000000010009cce4 MyApp.MyAppPlugin.(setSettings (MyApp.MyAppPlugin) -> (ObjectiveC.CDVInvokedUrlCommand) -> ()).(closure #1) (<imports>)
7  MyApp                       0x0000000100099aa0 partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned () -> (@unowned ()) to @callee_owned (@in ()) -> (@out ()) with unmangled suffix "102" (MyAppPlugin.swift:57)
8  MyApp                       0x0000000100099b10 partial apply forwarder for reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned (@in ()) -> (@out ()) to @callee_owned () -> (@unowned ()) with unmangled suffix "105" (MyAppPlugin.swift:57)
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001978213ac _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019782136c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019782d40c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1152
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000019782e75c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
13 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001979fd2e4 _pthread_wqthread + 816
```

The `(WmConfigModel.swift:84)` points to:

```
self.activeLanguage["name"] = tempDict["name"] as? String ?? activeLanguage["name"]
```

Comment: Is it possible both `tempDict["name"]` and `activeLanguage["name"]` are `nil`?

Comment: @AaronBrager `activeLanguage["name"]` can't be `nil` since it has hardcoded default value, `tempDict["name"]` might be `nil`

Comment: it has a hardcoded *initial* value, but don't you say you're replacing it later? Can you post that code? Or is the posted code the *only* place where it's updated?

Comment: @AaronBrager it's only one place I replace it. Maybe the best bet will be to create constant Dictionary and use 2 varaibles

Comment: Why not just use `if let name = tempDict["name"] { self.activeLanguage["name"] = name }`?

Comment: @AaronBrager I don't want to write `if` x 20. but it might be a point

Comment: It might be overkill, but you could use JSONHelper to parse your dictionary. Like I said, probably overkill but you won't have to write 20 if statements. `https://github.com/isair/JSONHelper`